# Grails extending HttpServletResponse metaclass

Tags: grails, groovy, metaclass

I need to add some functionality to the response.setHeader() method without creating a subclass. I use metaclass for it like this:

```
//grails bootstrap
  def overrideHttpResponse(){

    def old_impl = javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.metaClass.&setHeader
    println "Get set HEaders"
    println net.bull.javamelody.CounterServletResponseWrapper.metaClass.methods.findAll { it.name == "setHeader" }.join("\n")
    println old_impl
    //output
    //Get set HEaders
    //public void javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    // org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@6f62b062

    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.metaClass.setHeader = {String name, String value ->
      if(name == "Content-disposition"){
        value = value.replace(", "," ").replace(","," ")
      }
      println "In here"
      old_impl.invoke(name,value)
    }
  }
  //controller code
      withFormat {
      html result
      json {
        def map = exportService.getPackageMap(packageInstance, result.titlesList)

        def json = map as JSON

          response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"${filename}.json\"")
          response.contentType = "application/json"
          println response.class
          //class net.bull.javamelody.CounterServletResponseWrapper
          render json
      }
```

Any suggestions why the above is not working? I have added the printouts as comments, but the dont get the print from within the metaClass, the content disposition value is not changed. I also tried like this:

```
println "Get set HEaders"
println response.class.metaClass.methods.findAll { it.name == "setHeader" }.join("\n")
def old_impl = javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.metaClass.getMetaMethod("setHeader",[String,String] as Class[])
println old_impl
//Get set HEaders
//public void javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
//public abstract void javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.setHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

Also, inside my controller I have tried this, again without any changes on the returned filename:

```
   def old_impl = response.class.metaClass.getMetaMethod("setHeader",[String,String] as Class[])
   println old_impl
   //public abstract void javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.setHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

    response.class.metaClass.setHeader = {String name, String value ->
      if(name == "Content-disposition"){
        value = value.replace(", "," ").replace(","," ")
      }
      println "In here"
      old_impl.invoke(name,value)
    }
```